# Hide spin buttons in the react-select component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) component in my project. When I test on the Windows/Chrome browser, spin buttons show up.
[image]

I did some research and added the following styles to the root css of my app but it didn't work either.

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

How can I hide the spin buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply add this line to the component.
`components={{ DropdownIndicator:() => null, IndicatorSeparator:() => null }}`

Comment: Sorry I am not going to hide the dropdown indicator but the spin buttons from <input>.

Answer (score 0):

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Safari */
    -ms-appearance: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
    -moz-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none; /* Standard syntax */
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: I am testing in Windows / Chrome, does Windows OS make difference here?